# control is not entering into else-if block in my php code

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, if-statement

this is my php code which gets user info from html form and fetch data from database .
un fortunately,
the control doesn't enter into else if block .it is simply displaying all the rows in the database or nothing .

```
{
<?php
    include("config.php");
    echo "<form class='navbar-form' method='POST' action='#'>"; 

    $sqluser="SELECT DISTINCT username FROM user ORDER BY username ASC";
    $resultuser=mysqli_query($conn,$sqluser);

    echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><input  name='from_date' type='date' data-date-inline-picker='true' /></div>";
    echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><input  name='to_date' type='date' data-date-inline-picker='true' /></div>";
    echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><select  name='username' style='width:170px;height:33px;'>";
    echo "<option select='selected'>-- Username --</option>";
    while($ro1=mysqli_fetch_array($resultuser)){
        echo "<option value='".$ro1['username']."'>".$ro1['username']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><input type='submit' value='submit'></div>";

    echo "</form>";

    if(isset($_POST['username']))
    {
        $username=$_POST['username'];

        echo " <div align='center' style='margin-top:50px;'>";

        $sql="SELECT user.username,user.designation,
                    checkin.logdate,checkin.logintime,
                    checkin.loginhostname,checkin.loginipaddress,
                    checkin.logindevicetype,checkout.logouttime,
                    checkout.logouthostname,checkout.logoutipaddress,
                    checkout.logoutdevicetype 
                    FROM user 
                        INNER JOIN checkin ON user.username=checkin.username 
                        LEFT JOIN checkout ON user.username=checkout.username 
                                AND checkin.session_id=checkout.session_id 
                    ORDER BY checkin.ltime_stamp DESC LIMIT 10";

        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if($result->num_rows === 0){
            echo "<h4> No Records Found ! </b4>";
        } else {
            echo "<div style='overflow-x:auto;'>";  
            echo "<table border='1'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp&nbsp Date &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp Username &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp Designation &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp CheckInTime &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Hostname &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp Ipaddress &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp DeviceType &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp CheckOutTime &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Hostname &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp Ipaddress &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp DeviceType &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "</tr>";

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['logdate']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['designation']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['logintime']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['loginhostname']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['loginipaddress']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['logindevicetype']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['logouttime']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['logouthostname']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['logoutipaddress']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['logoutdevicetype']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

            }
            echo "</table>";
        }

        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['from_date'],$_POST['to_date'])){
        $from_date=date('Y-m-d',$_POST['from_date']);
        $to_date=date('Y-m-d',$_POST['to_date']);

        $sql="SELECT user.username,user.designation,checkin.logdate,
                    checkin.logintime,checkin.loginhostname,
                    checkin.loginipaddress,checkin.logindevicetype,
                    checkout.logouttime,checkout.logouthostname,
                    checkout.logoutipaddress,checkout.logoutdevicetype 
                    FROM user 
                        INNER JOIN checkin ON user.username=checkin.username 
                        LEFT JOIN checkout ON user.username=checkout.username 
                                AND checkin.session_id=checkout.session_id BETWEEN '$from_date' and '$to_date' 
                        ORDER BY checkin.ltime_stamp DESC 
                        LIMIT 10";

        echo $sql;
        echo $result->num_rows;

        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        echo " <div align='center' style='margin-top:50px;'>";
        if($result->num_rows === 0){
            echo "<h4> No Records Found ! </b4>";
        } else {
            echo "<div style='overflow-x:auto;'>";  
            echo "<table border='1'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp&nbsp Date &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp Username &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp Designation &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp CheckInTime &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Hostname &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp Ipaddress &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp DeviceType &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp CheckOutTime &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Hostname &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp Ipaddress &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "<th>&nbsp DeviceType &nbsp&nbsp</th>";
            echo "</tr>";

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['logdate']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['designation']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['logintime']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['loginhostname']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['loginipaddress']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['logindevicetype']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['logouttime']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['logouthostname']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['logoutipaddress']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['logoutdevicetype']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    } else {
        echo " <div align='center' style='margin-top:50px;'>";
        echo "<h3> Please provide data To Display User Information! </h3>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
    }
```

The form cotains 3 input fields,

```
1) from date 
2) to date 
3)username.
```

if i enter only the username, it should get data of the selected user from db. if i enter from n to dates, it shoukd get data between the given range from the db. but the problem is if i enter from n to dates, it is fetching all the rows from db.even if i give dates which is not available in db table

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: i cant read this much code what is your question..?

Comment: code is not aligned properly difficult to understand.  i think you are sending username always so its not entering into else if block

Comment: the form cotains 3 input fields, 1) from date 2) to date 3)username. if i enter only the username, it should get data of the selected user from db. if i enter from n to dates, it shoukd get data between the given range from the db. but the problem is if i enter from n to dates, it is fetching all the rows from db.even if i give dates which is not available in db table.

Comment: you are sending username always i think, and use else if like this elseif(isset($_POST['from_date']) && isset ($_POST['to_date'])){}

Comment: i tried using  elseif(isset($_POST['from_date']) && isset ($_POST['to_date']) but it's not working @ Appu Amruth

Comment: when you are trying how many parameters you are sending? all 3?

Comment: on submitting the form, i think all 3 values are sent @appu

Comment: thats the problem you are sending the username always so it will never enter to elseif condition, username is exist so if will execute. try without sending username and sending from and to both dates. then only it will enter to else if block.

Comment: could u explain me how to do it. i'm new to php coding. @appu

Comment: not php, you have to go through if else conditions. ok now just send from and to date , don't send username. then check.   refer this link for isset functionality http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: some columns are null .  even if i give some date values which are not in db , all the rows are fetched. @appu

Comment: $result->num_rows why are you  echoing this variable before executing query? may be that is the problem

Comment: because i wanted to know whether the control goes ther are not. i removed the line now.

Comment: now control is going inside to elseif rt? so within elseif some variable you are using without defining so you are getting error

Comment: i'm not getting error now, it is fetching all the rows which doesn't contain the dates given @appu

Comment: your query may be wrong and you are not comparing BETWEEN dates with any field. your query is wrong.

Comment: ok. got it. what should be changed in that query now? .  i need to get  uer details from user table , checkin info from checkin table n checkout info from checkout table.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore. There will be a few

Comment: as a beginner you try with one table then go for 2,3.. tables, better you refer mysql,  now you are joining 3 tables at a time you don't what is happening

Comment: it is not helping @Riggs. something is wrong with my query.

Comment: So what are the error messages?

Comment: Yes invalid syntax `LEFT JOIN checkout ON user.username=checkout.username 
                                AND checkin.session_id=checkout.session_id BETWEEN '$from_date' and '$to_date'`

Comment: i gave a where condition like "where checkin.logdate between from and to". it is working if i remove username input . i want this to work when both exist @appu

Comment: i gave a where condition like "where checkin.logdate between from and to". it is working if i remove username input . i want this to work when both exist @Riggs

Comment: can i stop the form to submit values which are not set to some value? @Appu

Comment: @siri use this elseif(isset($_POST['from_date'])&& isset ($_POST['to_date']) && isset ($_POST['username'])){} it will work if you send all 3 fields.. isset() will check if the value is exist or not if value exist it will return true else false

Comment: @Appu i need different outputs for both. if i enter only username , it should fetch all rows of that user in all 3 tables. if i enter dates it should fetch all the users info between the range.

Comment: ok when you are sending username are you sending from and to dates?

Comment: i'm submitting the form. so, s ofcourse while sending username, i'm sending to n from dates too @AppuAmruth

Comment: @siri if(isset($_POST['username']) && (isset($_POST['from_date']) && $_POST['from_date'] == '')&& (isset($_POST['to_date']) && $_POST['to_date'] == ''))
    {
        
      //write code here to fetch all the results    
    }else if(isset($_POST['from_date'])&& isset ($_POST['to_date'])){
        //write code here to fetch between results
    }else{
        //if you sent nothing
    } use this code later you optimize this

Comment: GOD! it's working nice with dates .now my username became an issue. whatever may be the username is. it is fetching all the rows :'( @AppuAmruth

Comment: ya modify your query to fetch the username which you are sending, somewhere use like this in your query user.username = ".$username."

Comment: if i use user.username = ".$username."  in the query i'm getting the error - " Trying to get property of non-object "  if i check to execute the query in db , i says " unknown column " @AppuAmruth

Comment: @siri am sorry use just username =".$username."

Comment: the same error persists on the same line of query @AppuAmruth

Comment: @siri give data base field name that contain's usernames instead of username

Comment: the column name is username @AppuAmruth

Comment: yes give that column name, still its giving error means you are using different column name which is not exist in table. check your query

Comment: $sql="SELECT user.username,user.designation,checkin.logdate,checkin.logintime,checkin.loginhostname,checkin.loginipaddress,checkin.logindevicetype,checkout.logouttime,checkout.logouthostname,checkout.logoutipaddress,checkout.logoutdevicetype FROM user INNER JOIN checkin ON user.userame=checkin.username 
LEFT JOIN checkout ON user.username=checkout.username AND checkin.session_id=checkout.session_id WHERE username=".$username." ORDER BY checkin.ltime_stamp DESC LIMIT 10"; @AppuAmruth this is my query.all the columns i've mentioned , do exist in the db.

Comment: @siri FROM user 
                        INNER JOIN checkin ON user.username=checkin.username 
                        LEFT JOIN checkout ON user.username=checkout.username 
                                AND checkin.session_id=checkout.session_id 
                                AND username=".$username."
                    ORDER BY checkin.ltime_stamp DESC LIMIT 10 try this
                    " still its giving error means write query table wise finally join.

Comment: i doesn't help , same error "Trying to get property of non-object" @AppuAmruth

Comment: can you try this query separately by executing...

Comment: "Column 'username' in on clause is ambiguous " this is what i get if i try to execute it in db @AppuAmruth

Comment: SELECT user.username,user.designation,checkin.logdate,checkin.login‌​time,checkin.loginho‌​stname,checkin.login‌​ipaddress,checkin.lo‌​gindevicetype,checko‌​ut.logouttime,checko‌​ut.logouthostname,ch‌​eckout.logoutipaddre‌​ss,checkout.logoutde‌​vicetype FROM user INNER JOIN checkin ON user.username=checkin.username LEFT JOIN checkout ON user.username=checkout.username WHERE checkin.session_id=checkout.session_id AND user.username=".$username." ORDER BY checkin.ltime_stamp DESC LIMIT 10 can you try this

Comment: got some new error in db "Unknown column 'checkin.loginâ€Œâ€‹â€Œâ€‹time' in 'field list' "  and the same error in webpage "Trying to get property of non-object" @AppuAmruth

Comment: @siri previously you posted query that is correct just use user.username instead just username

Comment: @siri can you write your query from beginning, then you will get to know what is the error.

Comment: @siri you write query for user table first then join with checkin table  if its working then you join with checkout, identify where you are getting error. still you are can't identify then post that query separately and ask question. hey its ok even i learned many things from you :)

Comment: ok, thank you @AppuAmruth

Comment: the error in my query is "INNER JOIN checkin ON user.userame=checkin.username"  here 'n' is missing in username. I found it . issue solved. @AppuAmruth

Comment: @siri great job. carry on.